# Are "ball" (formal event) and "ball" (sphere for playing with) etymologically related?

Tags: etymology, homophones, homographs

This is a ball:

[image: ballroom]
<sup>[source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_(dance_party)#/media/File:Wilhelm_Gause_Hofball_in_Wien.jpg)</sup>

But so is this:

[image: football]

<sup>[source](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Soccer_ball.svg/120px-Soccer_ball.svg.png)</sup>

Why do we use the same word for a [formal social gathering with dancing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_(dance_party)) and a [round toy for throwing and catching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball)?

Is there some kind of shared origin? If so, how did the word come to be used for such different things?

Or do the two similar-looking words actually come from different etymological roots?

Comment: On King Henry II of France's 34th birthday, a court jester famously loosed a pallet of billiard balls onto the dance floor while guests were vigorously engaged in a Minuet. Quite a scène ensued as dancers slipped on them and dropped willy-nilly, except the King himself who nimbly avoided the spherical hazards and ended with a flourish, balanced neatly upon one of them. Large dance parlours were henceforth called ballrooms, and those able to maintain purpose gracefully in chaotic situations were consequently said to be "on the ball".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ball as in 'sphere' comes from Norse 'bǫllr' /bɔlːr/, while ball as in 'dance party' comes from Latin 'ballare', which in turn became 'bal' (French for 'a dance'). Totally different roots, it's just one of those quirks of English having absorbed bits of so many different languages.

Edit as requested to provide a bit more detail:
'Ball' meaning 'sphere' turned up as we know it in Middle English, so sometime after the Norman conquest of Britain - though not from the French influence on the language (which is generally thought to have had a bigger impact on 'high' society's language, which is why so many words for things like politics and the legal system are borrowed from old French or Latin, and indeed the word 'ball' as in 'dance party'). I've not found anything to predate bǫllr from a quick bit of research, but we probably obtained that sometime after the Viking invasion. Bǫllr itself comes from the proto-Indo-European word 'bole', meaning 'inflate' or 'swell'.

During the Middle English era a lot of words with their roots in Germanic languages became a bit more simplified (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_English_phonology) so the trailing 'r', that was likely pronounced like an extraneous vowel on the end (think of things like 'olde worlde'), so we would end up with something that sounded a lot more like 'ball' - and eventually spelling was standardised a great deal more than it had before.

Ball as in 'dance party' could actually be traced back before Latin, to the Greek root 'ball' meaning 'to throw', like in the word 'ballistics' or the siege weapon 'ballista' - the Greek word meaning 'dance' it came from is 'ballizein': literally 'to throw your body' (think of your stereotypical Greek wedding and imagine how lively the dancing is!). Latin is the root of romance languages, including French, so it would've been loaned from there but I couldn't tell you a great deal about the changes in French I'm afraid. We definitely would have inherited the word into early Middle English following the Norman Conquest, though, since it's exactly the sort of thing that would apply to high society parties amongst the new nobility.

So yeah, it's pure coincidence that we use the same word for the two things; the words literally come from opposite ends of Europe, though they arrived in English within a couple of hundred years of each other as Britain repeatedly got its butt kicked by invaders!

Here's a good source for this sort of thing: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ball

Comment: This is a very brief answer. Any chance you could expand it a bit to explain how bǫllr and bal got used to mean the things they did, and maybe add some references?

Comment: Updated the answer with a bit more information; I hope this helps :)

Comment: I wouldn't read too much into the apparent "sudden simplification out of nowhere" during the Middle English period. All we have is written evidence, and it is quite likely that late pre-Conquest Old English writing was to language on the ground as written Latin was to early (or proto-) Romance. Apart from a little vocabulary, the biggest influence that the Normans had on English was to force a hiatus in the literature such that when it resumed it actually resembled the language being spoken.